# Javascript URL Validation failing for query string urls

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using following function to validate urls but its failing to validate url with query strings for example... `http://www.example.com/sample/?id=39949&affid=4994`

```
function checkURL(value) {
    var urlregex = new RegExp("^(http|https|ftp)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$");
    if (urlregex.test(value)) {
        return (true);
    }
    return (false);
}
```

Please help to fix this. thanks

Comment: seems to work fine?! as per fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k61mf6uv/1/). Could you provide a specific example that does not work

Comment: @OJay is there any option to accept all domains not just 'com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum', please help, thanks

Comment: Again, please provide the exact issue you are having. The regex matches those domain, and also any 2 letter domain (hence the `|[a-zA-Z]{2}` at the end of the domains. IF you are having issues with three letter domains, try `|[a-zA-Z]{2,3}`, or get rid of all the domain stuff, and just have something like `[a-zA-Z]+`

Comment: @OJay thanks alot for your help. I want to allow any domain tld, can you please post updated js code so i can pick your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears from comments that the issue is the top level domain is not matching. So to expand the rules for the domain matching, you could add `|[a-zA-Z]{2,3}` to the end instead of `|[a-zA-Z]{2}` which would mean there needs to be 2 or 3 alpha characters at the end. Or to eliminate the top level domain check completely, change all of the `com|edu|gov|int|` etc matches to simply `[a-zA-Z]+`  which is any alpha character one or more times

As follows

match `arpa|info|name|aero|coop|museum` or any 2 or 3 letter domain (removed the 2 or 3 letter ones as don't need them) :

```
function checkURL(value) {
    var urlregex = new RegExp("^(http|https|ftp)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(arpa|info|name|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2,3}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$");        
    return urlregex.test(value);
}
```

or match any alpha character domain (one or times) :

```
function checkURL(value) {
    var urlregex = new RegExp("^(http|https|ftp)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.[a-zA-Z]+)(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$");        
    return urlregex.test(value);
}
```